# Approval Process skips the approver after some time?

Tags: developer

I’m stumped and I hope you can help me. I have a requirement for a multistep approval process that’s already in place. For a specific approval step, I need to add functionality that waits for 48 hours to see if the approver made any action (approve or reject) if no steps made within 48 hours, it escalates to the next approver instead of sitting there in limbo. The only things I’ve found is involving either apex code or a workflow rule.

Are there any other way(s) of creating this??

Comment: Salesforce Orchestration would be useful here

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.